# When is the right time to use the DMR and the Battle Rifle?

Tags: halo-4

Halo 4 has both the DMR (see in Halo: Reach) and the Battle Rifle (first appeared in Halo 2, firing three-burst shots) and for the first time they both appear in the same game, avalible as a primary weapon in choosing your loadouts for multiplayer. However, which one should be used? I get the impression that the DMR is suited for medium-long range, while the Battle Rifle is for short-medium combat, but when I go into combat against someone with a DMR when using a Battle Rifle I always tend to lose.

The Halo 4 Strategy guide says the Battle Rifle is an "instant hit" weapon, so does this count against me for the "slower" bullets of the DMR?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends on a few factors:

- Range
- Your skill
- Enemy's skill

The DMR is more accurate at long-range, but the Battle Rifle is easier to use due to the burst fire.

Chances are if someone is beating you at mid-to-close range with the DMR, they are pretty skilled with it.  The single-shot nature of the gun makes it (normally) more difficult to use at close range.

If you find yourself losing often to the DMR at close range, I'd consider switching to it and seeing if you can't master it.  Granted, you'll probably see a performance drop for a while, but if you can nail every headshot as fast as you can fire with the DMR, you'll win.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I've seen, the answer is simply: **Always use the BR.**

What you mention about range is accurate. On paper the DMR should be slightly better at long range. The thing is, you have to be a ***really*** good shot to see the advantage. What the BR gives up in range and damage per shot it makes up for big time with its burst fire. When aimed at the general vicinity of the enemies head, I find I get many more headshots, simply due to the burst pattern.

Answer (score 2):

For anything other than really long range you want to use the BR. The spread will help with imperfect aim. But at long range the DMR is better if you have good enough aim.